# Flexbox preventing margins from being respected

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

I'm struggling to get a flexbox layout working with margins and `overflow: hidden`.

The carousel component I'm integrating uses this method to be responsive but as soon as a `display:flex` is applied to the parent, the `margin` and `overflow: hidden` properties are ignored as shown in the example below.

The top version is not nested in a flexbox where as the one below it is, and is not respecting the margins of the parent.

[image: flexbox issue with margins]

The issue is demonstrated in the code below and in this Plunker. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/qU1oq1Vq1X3FQMWLJiQk?p=preview

```css
body {
  margin: 400px;
}

.overflowHidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="overflowHidden">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <div class="overflowHidden">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know there are many similar questions on this topic but I couldn't find anything relating to my particular use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
.flex > div { overflow: hidden }
```

[revised demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nxHALLb6MEddeuNB6VxP?p=preview)

---

The first thing to note is that margins have nothing to do with this problem. Margins are, in fact, being respected. They are simply travelling with the element, which is expanding a container.

---

The non-flex div containers have `display: block` by default.

In a [**block formatting context**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting), when an image becomes too big to fit in a container with `overflow: hidden`, it simply disappears, as expected.

The parent divs and their margins remain stable and undisturbed.

However, in a [**flex formatting context**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers) the behavior is different.

First, you have three levels of divs in the flex example. You only have two in the block example. But that's not really important.

The key piece of information here is this:

> *When you apply `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` to an element it becomes a flex container and its children become flex items.* ***By default, flex items cannot be smaller than the size of their content. They have a default setting of `min-width: auto`.***

So, when an image becomes too big for its parent, the parent (if it's a flex item) must expand. But in your example, the parent of the image (`div.overflowHidden`) is not a flex item, it's a standard block element. So `overflow: hidden` is working fine (just like in the block example).

But the parent of the parent is a flex item. And its default setting is `min-width: auto`. And it cannot shrink below the size of its content (the image). So while the block example can remain on the screen at all times, the flex version will overflow the `body` / viewport, taking the right margin with it.

The solution is to override the `min-width: auto` default on the flex item. You can use:

- `min-width: 0`

OR

- `overflow: hidden`

More details here: [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed answer Michael. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that's happening exactly, but seems to work if you apply `.overflowHidden` to either an element that wraps the `flex` parent, or just apply it to the flex parent instead.

```css
body {
  margin: 400px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.overflowHidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="overflowHidden">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex overflowHidden">
  <div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="overflowHidden">
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400" />
  </div>
</div>
```